# unity broken :(

Tags: unity, ati, screen

So I updated my computer a while ago... bad choice. Now my desktop is all screwed up. Without unity running it runs just fine... but unity controls everything so its hard to do anything without it. What it is doing is stretching the windows and for that matter anything other than the side bar and top bar. Its so stretched you really cant do anything. I do not know how to pull any information about this to provide to the community so if you show me the command ill do it. :) my computer is custom built. It has a amd 64 proccessor and a radeon 4650. I am on 12.05. Dont upgrade to 12.10 because itll fail completely (since amd droped support for my card)

Comment: Check if you have Quantal's kernel and xorg installed with `dpkg -l | grep quantal`. If you do, removing the proprietary ATI driver should solve the problem. Use `jockey-text` to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Guess you have tried 
"sudo apt-get install unity"
 or 
"sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop".

If not, try any of them. If they don't work go for this: 
"sudo aptitude install unity".

This must work. I don't know what to tell you if this doesn't work too..

If you have installed compiz-config-settings manager it might have held broken packages. Uninstall all of them first and try the steps I mentioned above. - Prasanna